# Is separating source and header effective as using inline?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have been told that the compiler ignores `inline` or `__inline` keywords, unless told otherwise like VS.

So I thought of writing code like this:

```
class A {
public:
    inline A() {
         P(); //yep, works
    }
    inline void P() {
    }
}
```

Instead of separating it like this:

```
//.h
class A {
public:
    A();
    void P();
}

//.cpp
#include ".h"
A::A() {
    P();
}
void A::P() {
}
```

Out of pure laziness and love towards C#.

So the question is: are they both equally effective even in terms of optimization in every existing situation? There's no other role for inline keywords except inlining the function which is not true anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few misconceptions in your question:

- `inline` actually has an effect that is unrelated to optimization: It permits multiple definitions (so that you can put an inline definition in a header that is included in several compilation units).
- When you define methods "inline" (in the broader of writing it down in the class declaration), it's also, implicitly, `inline` in the sense of the keyword. So writing the keyword on these definitions is pointless.

As for performance: There actually is a difference, since in the first case the definition is visible in compilation units that include the header file (so the methods can be inlined), while in the latter -- assuming you don't have link-time optimization -- the definitions are not visible and can't be inlined or otherwise analyzed. This is a fairly minor advantage though: Most C and C++ code gets by just fine leaving 99% of functions "non-inline". Furthermore, there are downsides (code bloat, icache pressure, increased compile times), so **don't take this as reason to write method definitions in headers**. Writing it in an implementation file and only exporting the declarations is the standard way in C++ and having C# experience is not a good reason to deviate from this standard.

Comment: If the method is short, and the number of arguments is large, then inlining it will have a very large performance benefit

Comment: @LasseReinhold And how common is that, exactly? I don't really see what's your point. I know perfectly well that inlining is a powerful optimization, and haven't written to the contrary. But it's not an automatic win, so its use must be targeted and justified.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, compilers may choose to ignore `inline`, but there is a good reason for it: Inlining can significantly slow your program down. Inlining means larger code size, which means more stress on the instruction cache of your CPU, which means less performance. Compiler writers know this, and consequently have heuristics in place which `inline` hints to follow, and which not.

While you can put everything in header files in C++, it is not a good idea to do so:

1. Even that does not force inlining. The compiler must still emit the function in the object file, and the linker has the job of throwing the copies away. You pay for this in terms of compilation time, and get very little in return.
2. When you change code in a .cpp file, only that file must be recompiled; when you change a header, all dependent files must be recompiled. If everything is in a header, you always have to build your program as one big monolithic block. For a large project, this massively reduces the frequency of your test-change-build cycle, making you much less productive.

I would strongly advise you to embrace the differentiation between headers and implementation files in C/C++, it's really a huge time saver.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has the choice to ignore `inline`.

This does not mean it completely ignores the `inline`, it just takes it as a hint.

When you make everything in-line like this chances are you are gonna get a larger compiled file, as there will be a lot more inline than there usually would be.

Also you are writing in C++ not C#, so pure laziness and love towards C# is not an excuse for writing bad C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

GCC cannot inline a method if its method definition and caller are in different compilation units (.cpp files). So you would need to put the definition in the header.

Visual Studio may inline it if link time code generation is enabled, which it is by default with /O3.

In both cases, note that the "inline" keyword has changed meaning in C++ compared to C. It now has a semantical meaning, and not an inline hint.

You can use __forceinline in Visual Studio to enforce inlining - in practise it works in all cases where it's semantically possible.

For GCC you can use **attribute**((always_inline)), but GCC does not always obey it - it still compromises code size (unlike Visual Studio which always obeys it).

Comment: I am not sure how it answers the question; I think you misunderstood something.

Comment: GCC also supports link-time-optimizations with the -flto.